# Create new component based on existing one in Eagle 9

Tags: eaglecad

**How can I create a new component in Eagle 9 based on an already existing one?**

It used to be a relatively straightforward endeavor in all the previous versions prior to v9.0 but the process seems to have changed. There are plenty of tutorials explaining how to create a component from scratch, but so far I've found none that walks through the process of creating a new component based on an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s fairly simple. You force a symbol duplication and it asks you for a new name. You give it a new name and save it. Then you edit and save the symbol. Ditto the device and device name then delete the old symbol in the new device and install the new symbol. Then you may need to do the same with the footprint(s).

Finally, in the device editor reconcile symbol pin names with footprint numbers and you’re good to go.

Comment: Thanks for that. In the meantime Eagle support got back to me with this [Speed up your PCB Component Making](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhkE7YPXUOY) tutorial, which together with your answer makes for a powerful combo.